# How to force Picasso to cache and use a resized image next time the same image URL was requested

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I using Picasso to show image in my application. At some cases the image received are really huge and in those cases I want to resize the image and from now on use the resized image.

I'm using the following method of Picasso to receive the bitmap image:

```
articleVH.mTarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    if(bitmap != null) {
             articleVH.mCoverImage.setImageBitmap(Utils.getResizedBitmapIfNeeded(bitmap));
        } else {
             mTimelineViewCallback.getArticleImage(articleCoverData);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        mTimelineViewCallback.getArticleImage(articleCoverData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
};
```

Now I want that in case `Utils.getResizedBitmapIfNeeded(bitmap)` resizes the image, I want this resized image to be used the next time it will be requested.

How can this be done without using the resize(int, int) option which I know is cacheing the images but I can't use it.

Comment: Why can't you use resize()?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
Picasso
.with(context)
.load(your_image)
.resize(4000, 2000)
.onlyScaleDown() // the image will only be resized if it's bigger than 4000x2000 pixels.
.into(your_image_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I was thinking of doing it is as follows:

```
articleVH.mTarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        if(bitmap != null) {
            int[] resizedImageSize = Utils.getResizedImageSize(bitmap);
            if (bitmap.getHeight() == resizedImageSize[0] && bitmap.getWidth() == resizedImageSize[1]) {
                mPicasso.load(articleCoverData.mImageUrl).into(articleVH.mCoverImage);
            } else {
                mPicasso.load(articleCoverData.mImageUrl).resize(resizedImageSize[1], resizedImageSize[0]).into(articleVH.mCoverImage);
            }
        } else {
            mTimelineViewCallback.getArticleImage(articleCoverData);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        mTimelineViewCallback.getArticleImage(articleCoverData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
}
```

Where `getResizedImageSize` is:

```
public static int[] getResizedImageSize(@NonNull Bitmap originalBitmap) {
    int bitmapHeight = originalBitmap.getHeight();
    int bitmapWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();

    int[] originalSize = {bitmapHeight, bitmapWidth};

    if (!(bitmapHeight > Constants.IMAGE_EDGE_SIZE_LIMIT && bitmapWidth > Constants.IMAGE_EDGE_SIZE_LIMIT)){
        return originalSize;
    }

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Original Bitmap: Height: " + bitmapHeight + " Width: " + bitmapWidth);
    }

    float ratio = bitmapHeight / Constants.IMAGE_EDGE_SIZE_LIMIT;
    bitmapHeight = Constants.IMAGE_EDGE_SIZE_LIMIT;
    bitmapWidth = (int) (bitmapWidth * (1 / ratio));

    int[] newSize = {bitmapHeight, bitmapWidth};
    return newSize;
}
```

Take in mind that it means the image is going to be loaded twice. Once so you could get the size of it and second time for the resize and storing this image into the cache resized.